# C# use an operation as a parameter

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a function where I can give it an operation `>` `<` `==` `!=` etc.
I was wondering if it is possible to set one of these as a parameter to a function,

ie: `UseOperator("test", >, 0)`

If not what would be the best way to handle something like this? Maybe an enum?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most natural approach would be to pass a delegate, IMO, e.g. of type `Func<int, int, bool>`. Unfortunately you can't convert an operator directly to a delegate - but you could write methods pretty simply and use method group conversions:

```
public void UseOperator(string name, Func<int, int, bool> op, int value)
{
    ...
}

public static bool GreaterThan(int x, int y, value)
{
    return x > y;
}

UseOperator("test", GreaterThan, 0);
```

Marc Gravell's work on [generic operators](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html) in [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) may be useful to you.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible but you could use function delegates:

```
UseOperator("test", (x, y) => x > y, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about parsing the operator as a string value?

```
UseOperator("Test", ">", 0)

private void UseOperator(string str1, string operator, int intVlue)
{
   switch(operator)
   {
       case ">":
        //.....
   }
}
```